# rsp file in mono

Tags: c#, mono

The book of [CLR via C# 3rd](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) explains about the default global CSC.rsp file in page 35. What's the equivalent rsp file in mono?

I searched the mono directory to find

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/mono/4.0/xbuild.rsp
```

which doesn't have nothing in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mono compiler currently doesn't use a separate file: the list of default assemblies is hardcoded in the source file (mcs/driver.cs in the sources).
By default only System and System.Xml are loaded.
The above holds for the command-line compiler, xbuild, Monodevelop or other tools may have different default sets themselves.

A somewhat equivalent for mono is the pkg-config file dotnet.pc, but you have to use the command line option -pkg to load it explicitly:

gmcs -pkg:dotnet myprogram.cs